# 3.5 inch floppy access functions only once per session

Tags: 14.04, floppy

System is Ubuntu 14.04 server with gnome gui installed after.  Last software updater run was today, CE 2016-12-10.  In testing numerous old 3.5 inch [floppies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk), I have found that (a) defective floppies appear to cause floppy drive light to stay on until the machine is powered down, and floppy drive does nothing else for remainder of session, and (b) non-defective floppies are read only once after being inserted in the floppy drive.  In other words, a functioning floppy can be ejected, and drive light goes off, but when either the same or a different functioning floppy is inserted, its directory cannot be read except by rebooting the computer.  In contrast, booting the machine to an old [MSDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) 6.22 floppy permits functioning floppy directories to be read one after another.  Question is: how can the floppy drive function be extended to more than one directory read per session?